# How to keep a list of CssColor instances?

Tags: gwt

I have something like this:

```
List<CssColor> colors = new ArrayList<CssColor>();
colors.add(CssColor.make("#f00"));
```

and I can use it just fine in dev mode:

```
context2d.setFillStyle(colors.get(0));
```

when I compile in production and run it, I get an exception. The stack trace I'm getting:

```
Unknown.RuntimeException_0
    Unknown.ClassCastException_0
    Unknown.dynamicCastJso
    Unknown.$getFillStrokeStyle   
    Unknown.$drawMyScene
    ...
```

If I try using a CssColor instance that is defined like so:

```
public static final CssColor RED = CssColor.make("#f00");

context2d.setFillStyle(RED);
```

that works fine in production mode too. Is it not possible to keep a collection of CssColor instances?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to the dynamic casting checking. It is known issue, you can read more about it here [GWT: How to avoiding calls to dynamicCast and canCastUnsafe in generated JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690169/gwt-how-to-avoiding-calls-to-dynamiccast-and-cancastunsafe-in-generated-javascr) or just googling for : `gwt dynamic cast checking`.

There is instant solution for your problem, but I am not sure if it is optimal. If you are using maven add gwt-compile parameter `disableCastChecking`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.1</version>
  <configuration>
          ...
          <disableCastChecking>true</disableCastChecking>
           ...
  </configuration>
```

If you are not using maven then just add the gwt-compile paramter: 
`-XdisableCastChecking`

Comment: This doesn't appear to explain *why* the error happens in prod mode only, since dynamic cast checks just emulate in JavaScript what Java includes automatically.

Comment: @ColinAlworth, additionaly you can take a look on the CSSColor implementation : http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.gwt/gwt-servlet/2.5.0-rc1/com/google/gwt/canvas/dom/client/CssColor.java, where you can see, that this class behaves diferently in production mode and in development mode.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, could be this workaround:

```
//hold list of objects
List<Object> colors = new ArrayList<Object>();
colors.add(CssColor.make("#f00"));
Object fillStyle =  colors.get(0);

// create new csscolor
CssColor newColor = CssColor.make(fillStyle.toString());
context.setFillStyle(newColor);
```

But this is definately not elegant and should be used only when you have no other choice.

Another workaround (again) is using one-element table instead of the object itself:

```
 List<CssColor[]> colors = new ArrayList<CssColor[]>();
 colors.add(new CssColor[] { CssColor.make("#f00") });
 CssColor fillStyle = colors.get(0)[0];
 context.setFillStyle(fillStyle);
```

Comment: Hmmm yeah I might as well just keep a list of strings then? I'm trying to avoid having to parse these string css color definitions, because this will be done in a draw loop - worried this might be a drag.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I hope you find the solution, I am also currios about it:)